# Easy timeout for a CFWriteStreamWrite/CFReadStreamWriter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sockets, network-programming

Working on `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` is always convenient:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
        (CFStringRef) hostnameOrIp,
        aPort,
        &readStream,
        &writeStream);
```

as it gets you the goods (a r and w pipe) right away. Unfortunately `CFReadStreamRead` and `CFWriteStreamRead` block. Is there a clean way to set timeout on this (e.g. with a streamOption) ?  They are running in a thread - and as there are quite a few going on in parallel - would like to avoid runloop/signals - as any other pending read/writes should not be interrupted).

Thanks,

Dw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable` to check if something is available. If yes, `CFReadStreamRead` will not block. Or you can set client (`CFReadStreamSetClient`) and listen for notifications (`kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` in your case).